# awk remove two row based on one row

Tags: awk

The input file has 2 columns, `column 1` has numbers and `column 2` with the distance between `row2-row1` of `column1`:

```
30  30
40  10
60  20
110  50
130  20
180  50
190  10
```

If the value in `column2<20`, I'd like to remove this line and one line above this one because the distance of this two data points is low, and has to remove both lines.

expect output:

```
60  20 
110  50
130  20
```

Or if someone knows how to subtract `column 1` `row1-row2`, and generate the following output then maybe can filter out this two points by `awk '$2<20 || $3>-20'` ?

output:

```
 30  30   -10
 40  10   -20
 60  20   -50
 110  50  -20
 130  20  -50
 180  50  -10
 190  10
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try `awk '$2>=20' file`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and help with the question format. I have to change the upper line column 2 contains a number >than 20

Comment: Your question is tagged **[tag:awk]**, but I don't see any awk code in your question. Please add your work so far, and we'll try to help you fix it.

Comment: The original file only has the first column, I used `awk '{print $1"\t"$1-p} {p=$1}' file>output` to calculate the distance between points and output file with the second column. Then I have no clue to remove both lines if distance <20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becomes easier to handle by reversing the input line wise

```
$ tac ip.txt 
190  10  
180  50
130  20
110  50
60  20
40  10
30  30
```

Now, if second column value is <20, don't print that line and the one following it. After that, reverse again

```
$ tac ip.txt | awk '$2<20{getline; next} 1' | tac
60  20
110  50
130  20
```

- `getline` will fetch the next record and `next` will skip the rest of code. In effect, this will skip line with second column value less than 20 and the line following it
- `1` idiomatic way to print current record

Comment: Thank you! This command worked very well! Could you please explain some more about the awk command?

Comment: @Ellie added some detail, would also suggest https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html and https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/awk/topics